# 3dsmax linear rotation controller and curve editor

Tags: animation, 3d, 3dsmax

I have an animated object converted from Euler XYZ rotation controller to linear rotation controller.

The animation is fine everything is looking good. But there are no keys in curve editor only in dope sheet. The whole rotation channel is missing.

Is this working like intended. I didn't find the explanation in 3ds Max documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear controller for rotation is different from let's say Linear Float in that it stores quaternion values and they can't be displayed as a curve. If you want to modify the key values from within curve editor, use Euler XYZ instead and assign Linear Float controllers to each of the axes. That way, you will have linear motion interpolation inbetween keys and also individual curves to work with.